# Docker: Cannot start docker daemon, cannot kill container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

So I'm having this issue where Docker has decided to keel over on my Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine, hosted on VirtualBox.

When I first boot my VM, no docker commands work at all. Even basic commands such as `docker help` and `docker version` hang indefinitely, as do system commands that interact with docker (for example, `sudo service docker [options]` will hang).

I tried `sudo dockerd --debug`, through which I found out that the `var/run/docker.pid` file was the issue:

```
root@david-VirtualBox:~$ dockerd --debug 
INFO[2020-11-16T13:01:11.177637329Z] Starting up                                  
failed to start daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid
```

I went and deleted the docker.pid file, then attempted the command again. This time, I got a different output reporting that it failed to start the daemon:

```
root@david-VirtualBox:/# dockerd --debug
INFO[2020-11-16T13:09:41.943314961Z] Starting up                                  
DEBU[2020-11-16T13:09:41.944098502Z] Listener created for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock) 
INFO[2020-11-16T13:09:41.944468539Z] detected 127.0.0.53 nameserver, assuming systemd-resolved, so using resolv.conf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf 
DEBU[2020-11-16T13:09:41.944911830Z] Golang's threads limit set to 71280          
INFO[2020-11-16T13:09:41.945385664Z] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2020-11-16T13:09:41.945410177Z] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2020-11-16T13:09:41.945442019Z] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2020-11-16T13:09:41.945481992Z] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
DEBU[2020-11-16T13:09:41.945451065Z] metrics API listening on /var/run/docker/metrics.sock 
INFO[2020-11-16T13:09:41.949860396Z] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2020-11-16T13:09:41.950283701Z] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2020-11-16T13:09:41.950370138Z] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2020-11-16T13:09:41.950401555Z] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
DEBU[2020-11-16T13:09:41.952229031Z] Using default logging driver json-file       
DEBU[2020-11-16T13:09:41.952481958Z] [graphdriver] priority list: [btrfs zfs overlay2 fuse-overlayfs aufs overlay devicemapper vfs] 
DEBU[2020-11-16T13:09:41.972318409Z] processing event stream                       module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
DEBU[2020-11-16T13:09:41.990153845Z] backingFs=extfs, projectQuotaSupported=false, indexOff="index=off,"  storage-driver=overlay2
INFO[2020-11-16T13:09:41.990191679Z] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2 
DEBU[2020-11-16T13:09:41.990211633Z] Initialized graph driver overlay2            
DEBU[2020-11-16T13:09:42.232203720Z] No quota support for local volumes in /var/lib/docker/volumes: Filesystem does not support, or has not enabled quotas 
DEBU[2020-11-16T13:09:43.228522173Z] Cleaning up old mountid : start.             
failed to start daemon: error while opening volume store metadata database: timeout
```

From here, the docker commands start semi-working - for example, `docker version` will return the expected version info, but will end with `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`.

At this stage, I checked the process with `service --status-all` which indicated that the service was stopped (`[ - ]  docker`). I checked the details with `service docker status`. This indicated that there was a container that did not exit properly, which is messing the service up:

```
root@david-VirtualBox:/# service docker status
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Mon 2020-11-16 12:59:30 GMT; 32min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 2299 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 30
     Memory: 155.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─2299 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Nov 16 12:59:31 david-VirtualBox dockerd[2299]: time="2020-11-16T12:59:31.277141877Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Nov 16 12:59:31 david-VirtualBox dockerd[2299]: time="2020-11-16T12:59:31.277175560Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil>>
Nov 16 12:59:31 david-VirtualBox dockerd[2299]: time="2020-11-16T12:59:31.277504809Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Nov 16 12:59:32 david-VirtualBox dockerd[2299]: time="2020-11-16T12:59:32.086919338Z" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
Nov 16 12:59:34 david-VirtualBox dockerd[2299]: time="2020-11-16T12:59:34.809584302Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit"
Nov 16 12:59:34 david-VirtualBox dockerd[2299]: time="2020-11-16T12:59:34.809620318Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support CPU realtime scheduler"
Nov 16 12:59:34 david-VirtualBox dockerd[2299]: time="2020-11-16T12:59:34.809667654Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight"
Nov 16 12:59:34 david-VirtualBox dockerd[2299]: time="2020-11-16T12:59:34.809685962Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight_device"
Nov 16 12:59:34 david-VirtualBox dockerd[2299]: time="2020-11-16T12:59:34.809995542Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Nov 16 12:59:45 david-VirtualBox dockerd[2299]: time="2020-11-16T12:59:45.004470995Z" level=info msg="Container bcbf2dcf0dea989cee6a5f92cc9fcf8d29f4e29b7cf0fc8e119a0e17f3a29235 failed to exit>
lines 1-21/21 (END)
```

Herein lies the issue though - I cannot start docker in order to kill that container. The command needs the Docker daemon to be running, yet all the commands I've tried to restart the service just hang indefinitely. Both `service` and `systemctl` don't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** After performing these steps, `ps -eax | grep docker` produces the following output:

```
root@david-VirtualBox:/# ps -eax | grep docker
   3787 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=en_GB:en PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin NOTIFY_SOCKET=/run/systemd/notify LISTEN_PID=3787 LISTEN_FDS=1 LISTEN_FDNAMES=docker.socket INVOCATION_ID=cf888947b40240069005c1553c951633 JOURNAL_STREAM=9:49757
   3843 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto docker SHELL=/bin/bash COLORTERM=truecolor SUDO_GID=1000 LANGUAGE=en_GB:en SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/su SUDO_USER=david PWD=/ LOGNAME=root XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority HOME=/root LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36: LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s TERM=xterm-256color LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s USER=root DISPLAY=:0 SHLVL=0 PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin SUDO_UID=1000 MAIL=/var/mail/root OLDPWD=/run _=/usr/bin/grep
```

These processes keep resurrecting themselves with different PIDs when I try to kill them, both with `sudo kill <pid>` and `sudo kill -9 <pid>`. Could these be zombie processes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docker containers are stored in the default location at `/var/lib/docker/` on Linux. If you can identify the container and delete this, and then try to start docker. If you are successful and you can run the `docker ps -a` command successfully, then you can start deleting traces of this container.

Note: I would snapshot your VM before attempting to try this.

Comment: Thank you so, SO much! I deleted the container and restarted my VM, now docker is working perfectly. Thank you so much, you have saved me a lot of hassle!